# Parsing coordinates from cin input c++

Tags: c++

How I should parse this? I'm asking 4 coordinates which you input like this: 1 3 4 3 and then if you just input 'q' and press enter it should exit. Same as if you replace some of the coordinates with 0 or alphabets. I'm quite stuck now and not sure how I'm supposed to do this in c++, now I'm just getting errors if my inputs contains alphabets or 0 and I can't input just one q. Example inputs:

```
Enter two cards (x1, y1, x2, y2), or q to quit: q
program quits
Enter two cards (x1, y1, x2, y2), or q to quit: 1 a 3 4
invalid coordinates
Enter two cards (x1, y1, x2, y2), or q to quit: 1 4 3 4
valid coordinates
```

```
bool check_coordinates(Game_board_type& g_board, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2,
                       int factor1, int factor2) {

  if (x1 == 'q' or x2 == 'q' or x1 == 'q' or y2 == 'q') {
    std::cout << GIVING_UP << endl;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

  } else if (g_board.at(y1 - 1).at(x1 - 1).get_visibility() == 2 or
             g_board.at(y2 - 1).at(x2 - 1).get_visibility() == 2) {
    std::cout << INVALID_CARD << std::endl;
    return false;
  } else if (isalpha(x1) or isalpha(x2) or isalpha(y1) or isalpha(y2) or
             x1 <= 0 or x2 <= 0 or y1 <= 0 or y2 <= 0) {
    std::cout << INVALID_CARD << std::endl;
    return false;
  } else if (x1 > factor2 or x2 > factor2 or y1 > factor1 or y2 > factor1) {
    std::cout << INVALID_CARD << std::endl;
    return false;
  } else if (x1 == x2 and y1 == y2) {
    std::cout << INVALID_CARD << std::endl;
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}

int main() {
  int x1;
  int x2;
  int y1;
  int y2;
std::cout << player.get_name() << ": " << INPUT_CARDS;
cin >> x1 >> y1 >> x2 >> y2;
if (check_coordinates(game_board, x1, y1, x2, y2, factor1, factor2)) {
  break;
}
}
```

Comment: If you convert to `int` _before_ checking what the input really is, your opportunities for handling the case where it is _not_ an `int` are kind of limited to checking failbit (see: [`operator>>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt)). That's why it normally works better to just read strings, and then you can check what's in them before trying (and maybe failing) to convert the string to an int.

Comment: I'm so confused with c++ atm tbh. Not sure what to do with it. Coming from python all these datatypes and using them etc. makes me really confused.

Comment: Fixed datatypes are one of the keys to C++'s speed. The more that's known at compile time, the faster your program will be. You are going to have to sort them out or C++ will remain opaque.

Comment: Yeah, I think this is the last course I touch c++. I'll stick with python and java onward.

Comment: Java's typing is almost as strict as C++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String handling and interactive input are exactly the things that C++ is *worst* for, compared to almost any scripting language. They're usually string-oriented and/or weakly- or dynamically-typed. This means you can often write optimistic code, and if it *does* fail, you can probably recover.

In order to handle string input in a strongly-typed language, you need to think about when you know what type the input really has. For example,

```
bool check_coordinates(Game_board_type& g_board, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2,
                   int factor1, int factor2)
```

should just be passed integers. The parameters are type `int`, so you must already have figured out that you got, for example, `"1"` but not `"q"`. If you got `"q"`, you won't even have three more coordinates to read - it doesn't fit at all.

Now, you're currently using [`operator>>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) to do [formatted input](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/FormattedInputFunction), which has some problems: specifically, it can be hard to keep track of the stream state and which variables are really initialized. Read the section about `failbit` in particular.

That is, in

```
std::cin >> x1 >> y1 >> x2 >> y2;
if (check_coordinates(game_board, x1, y1, x2, y2, factor1, factor2)) {
  break;
}
```

you have to check something like `if (!std::cin) { handle_input_error(); }` before you can call `check_coordinates`.

It's more robust to just read a whole line with [`getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline), and *then* test whether it contains a `"q"`, or four integers, or something else. You still need to figure out what to do with "something else", but at least the original input wasn't discarded by the formatted input function because it couldn't perform the conversion you asked for.